# Remote access to Heroku Postgres Hobby tier without SSL

Tags: heroku, heroku-postgres

Why am I able to access a hobby-dev Postgres in Heroku without SSL?

This is my Node code:

```
const { Client } = require('pg');
const connectionString = process.env.DATABASE_URL;

const client = new Client({
  connectionString: connectionString,
  ssl: false
})
```

`heroku pg:credentials:url DATABASE` returns `sslmode=require` yet I am also able to connect remotely with `psql DATABASE_URL` without the `sslmode=require` as a query param.

According to [Heroku docs and code samples](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql#heroku-postgres-ssl) it shouldn't be the case. The only thing that could explain it is that Heroku does not support encryption at rest [on the Hobby tier](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-plans) so why should it in transit?

Comment: Are you entirely sure about this? I've always had to connect over SSL.

Comment: yeah @Chris, I contacted Heroku and they told me that it's not enforced from the server side, see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I contacted Heroku support and the response I got is that it's currently **not** enforced on the [server side](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/libpq-ssl.html)

Their data team confirms this is a "known-but-undocumented" thing. The docs unfortunately are misleading e.g. [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql#heroku-postgres-ssl) and [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql#remote-connections):

> If you leave off sslmode=require you will get a connection error

Answer (score 0):

Encryption at rest has little to do with secure connections to the Postgres instance. After all, 'at rest' is quite the opposite of moving bytes back and forth between the client and the database host.

This is almost certainly due to the configuration of the database host itself but it's impossible to say for certain. At a guess, the reasoning here is to lower the difficulty in using the service since the hobby tier is free and popular with hobbyist and newer developers.

Comment: Yes, this was my guess as well but it's not just for the hobby tier, see my answer.